# How to avoid enumitem label appearing multiple times for nested enumerations?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I'd like to use the `enumitem` package to come up with the following enumeration:

```
Article 1: An article
    Article 1.1: A sub article
    Article 1.2: A sub article
```

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\setlist{label*=\textbf{Article \arabic*.}}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item An article
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item A sub article
        \item A sub article
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following:

[image]

How can I adjust the code so that the word "Article" appears only once?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594835/setting-counters-with-enumerate-and-newlists can give you some pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you replace

```
\setlist{label*=\textbf{Article \arabic*.}}
```

at a minimum with

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{Article \arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi\textbf{\arabic*.}}
```

Additionally, you should also specify the option `leftmargin=*` for the level-1 enumerate list, so that the word "Article" doesn't jut out prominently into the left-hand margin. And, if you intend to cross-reference items in article lists, you should also specify suitable `ref` options.

A full MWE (minimum working example and its associated output -- the blue color comes from the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{Article \arabic*.},
                      ref  =\arabic*,
                      leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\textbf{Article \arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.},
                      ref  =\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item An article \label{item:1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item A sub article
        \item A sub article \label{item:1.2}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Cross-references to articles \ref{item:1} and \ref{item:1.2}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the formatting at each level separately in the optional argument of `\setlist`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{articleenum}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[articleenum]{label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[articleenum,1]{label=\textbf{Article \arabic*.}}
\begin{document}

\begin{articleenum}
    \item An article
    \begin{articleenum}
        \item A sub article
        \item A sub article
        \begin{articleenum}
            \item A subsub article
        \end{articleenum}
    \end{articleenum}
\end{articleenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to add the option `leftmargin=*` to `\setlist[articleenum,1]{...}` so that the word "article" that's prefixed to article items doesn't just out into the left-hand margin.